# Dynamically discovering underlying database in DataMapper

Tags: ruby, database-connection, datamapper

In Rails, I programmatically discover the underlying database via:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name
```

which returns "MySQL", "PostgreSQL", etc.

What's the equivalent call for DataMapper?  The best I've come up with is:

```
DataMapper.repository(:default).adapter.options["scheme"]
```

Is that the approved mechanism?

Comment: `DataMapper.repository(:default).adapter.options["scheme"]` Seems to be working fine for me. Is there an issue with it?

Comment: If that's the documented and approved mechanism, then you can answer "Yes" and get the point.

Comment: For instance, how about `DataMapper::Repository.adapters[:default].options[:adapter]` ? It gives the same result in my environment.  My concern is that options are (or can be) unique to a specific adapter, so even though options["scheme"] works for postgres, there's no guarantee it will work for mysql or sqlite.